# Circle animation in different directions with Canvas and TimerTask

Tags: android, animation, canvas

How to make that circles rotate in different directions?I have to make a Solar system animation.In the center is Sun and the planet rotate around sun with different direction and speed.Problem is that all circles are turning in clockwise directions and the degrees in rotate() method is negative  for blue and gray circle...Thanks in advance

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView imageView;
Timer timer;
Canvas canvas;
Paint paint, paint1, paint2, paint3, paint4;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1000, 1500, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.eraseColor(Color.parseColor("#EBEBEB"));
    canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);

    paint = new Paint();
    paint1 = new Paint();
    paint2 = new Paint();
    paint3 = new Paint();
    paint4 = new Paint();

    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    paint1.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    paint3.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    paint4.setColor(Color.GRAY);


    canvas.drawCircle(500f, 750f, 130, paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(400f, 560f, 51, paint1);
    canvas.drawCircle(750f, 920f, 48, paint2);
    canvas.drawCircle(300f, 1100f, 45, paint3);
    canvas.drawCircle(320f, 300f, 42, paint4);


    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(
                    new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            animationFrame();

                        }
                    }
            );
        }
    }, 3000, 80);


}

private void animationFrame() {

    canvas.drawColor(Color.parseColor("#EBEBEB"));

    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    canvas.drawCircle(500f, 750f, 130f, paint);


    if (paint1 != null | paint3 != null) {
        paint1.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawCircle(400f, 560f, 51f, paint1);
        canvas.rotate(10f, 500f, 750f);

        paint3.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        canvas.drawCircle(350f, 1050f, 45, paint3);
        canvas.rotate(30f, 500f, 750f);
    }
    if (paint2 != null | paint4 != null) {
        paint2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawCircle(720f, 950f, 48, paint2);
        canvas.rotate(-10f, 500f, 750f);

        paint4.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        canvas.drawCircle(290f, 330f, 42, paint4);
        canvas.rotate(-25f, 500f, 750f);
    }


    imageView.invalidate();
}
```